# Grouping and hierarchical mapping with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to transform some data by using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) groupBy and map. Here is sample data:

```
var data = [
{name: 'x', qty: 0, rate: 10},
{name: 'x', qty: 10, rate: 2},
{name: 'y', qty: 5, rate: 20},
{name: 'y', qty: 55, rate: 11}]
```

I need that data in the format:

```
var data = [
{name: 'x', pricing: [{qty: 0, rate: 10}, {qty: 10, rate: 2}]},
{name: 'y', pricing: [{qty: 5, rate: 20}, {qty: 55, rate: 11}]}]
```

The following is my attempt:

```
var m = _.chain(data)
.groupBy(data, 'name')
.map( function(i) {
  return {
    name: _.first(i).name,
    pricing: _.map(i, function(r) {
      return _.pick(r, ['qty', 'rate'])
    })
  }
})
```

This produces

```
[{
    "name": "x",
    "pricing": [
      {"qty": 0, "rate": 10},
      {"qty": 10, "rate": 2},
      {"qty": 5,"rate": 20},
      {"qty": 55,"rate": 11}]
}]
```

I've been unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe this isn't even valid and there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map new object and get the picked values.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'x', qty: 0, rate: 10 }, { name: 'x', qty: 10, rate: 2 }, { name: 'y', qty: 5, rate: 20 }, { name: 'y', qty: 55, rate: 11 }],
    result = _(data)
        .groupBy('name')
        .map((pricing, name) => ({
            name,
            pricing: _.map(pricing, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['qty', 'rate']))
        }))
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use lodash for this - standard Javascript array methods work just fine. Reduce into an object indexed by `name`, then get that object's values:

```js
var data = [
{name: 'x', qty: 0, rate: 10},
{name: 'x', qty: 10, rate: 2},
{name: 'y', qty: 5, rate: 20},
{name: 'y', qty: 55, rate: 11}]

const obj = data.reduce((a, { name, ...rest }) => {
  if (!a[name]) a[name] = { name, pricing: [] };
  a[name].pricing.push(rest);
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(obj);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `reduce()`

```js
var data = [
{name: 'x', qty: 0, rate: 10},
{name: 'x', qty: 10, rate: 2},
{name: 'y', qty: 5, rate: 20},
{name: 'y', qty: 55, rate: 11}]

let res = data.reduce((ac,a) => {
  let i = ac.findIndex(x => x.name === a.name);
  if(i === -1) i = ac.push({name:a.name,pricing:[]}) - 1
  ac[i].pricing.push({qty:a.qty,rate:a.rate});
   return ac;
},[])
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually fine, except for a small mistake. You start a chain with `data`, and then you try to groupBy the `data`. Since non of the items return `true` for this predicate, all are bundled under a single group, and this is the reason for your single object.

You need to change `.groupBy(data, 'name')` to `.groupBy('name')`.

Example:

```js
var data = [{ name: 'x', qty: 0, rate: 10 }, { name: 'x', qty: 10, rate: 2 }, { name: 'y', qty: 5, rate: 20 }, { name: 'y', qty: 55, rate: 11 }];

var m = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy('name') // group by name, and not by data, 'name'
  .map(function(i) {
    return {
      name: _.first(i).name,
      pricing: _.map(i, function(r) {
        return _.pick(r, ['qty', 'rate'])
      })
    }
  })

console.log(m);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```